# How can i add and access a folder of images to my java program (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a simple java game. I want to put this game on a flash drive and play it on other computers. How can i make my Images folder part of the java package and access them from the program instead of using filepaths that will only work for my computer "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\mypic.png"

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getRoots()[0];
```

or

```
FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory();
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Thank you! i have never used FileSystemView and i was messing around with it and am glad you brought to my attention that this exists.

Comment: If the answer worked for you ,, you may 'Accept' it as it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution, Two things i was doing wrong, I added my library to the wrong part of my project. At first i was adding my image package under source packages and it was named only "images". When I instead added my package to source packages with the name "myproject.images" (myproject = whatever your project name is) i was able to access my images using this code then -

```
try{
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/water.jpg"));
}catch(Exception e){}
```